# Get nested object with httpClient in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I am trying to get the nested object to display in the template with a get request. The issue is it display the main properties of my object, though, the nested object.

```
export class User {
  userId: number;
  userName: string;
  password: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  role: number;
  inforamation: Information;
}
```

This is my model which can show user properties but not information.

```
getAllUsers(){
    const header = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json'
    });
    return this.usersapiservice.getData(this.REST_API_SERVER, {headers : header});
  }



ngOnInit(){
this.getAllUsers().subscribe((data: User[]) => {
      this.users = data;
    });
}
```

In my html

```
{{users.firstname}} // work

{{users.information.adress}} // Does not work
```

Comment: Can you do `console.log(this.users)` after the line `this.users = data;` and please check how the object looks like in the console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a couple of issues.  In the `User` class, you misspelled one of the properties as `inforamation`, but in the template, the property is spelled correctly as `information`.

If you have an array of `User`s that you want to render, you can use Angular's `*ngFor` to iterate through them, as shown below:

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users">
  {{user.firstName}}
  {{user.information.address}}
</div>
```

Comment: Woow I didn't expected that. It was the misspelled property "Inforamation" . thx a lot

Comment: No problem! Glad that helped. This kind of error is usually logged in the console of your browser.  If you're using Chrome, you can open the console by right-clicking anywhere on the webpage and clicking the "Inspect" option, then navigating to the "Console".